# How do I make a div NOT follow me as I scroll?

Tags: html

I have a description box on my blog that is stuck. It follows you as you scroll and it is a rather long description box so it doesn't show the whole thing on the page unless you "CTRL + minus" and since it follows the way you scroll, it doesn't scroll down the description box to see the whole length of the description box. What can I edit to make it not stuck? I'm not that great with HTML

Comment: Do you have some CSS/HTML we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the css that says `position: fixed` on that block. That's my best guess without seeing any html/css

Comment: so just completely delete that one line?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the CSS: `position: fixed` that fixes the div into the page, just remove the `position: fixed` and it should work fine.